# Code execution allocates all memory until it is killed by OOM (linux) probably at code initialization. Ideas for debugging such a problem?

Tags: c++, linux, fortran, elf, hpc

I am having a really weird problem with some code. I am trying to debug a C++/Fortran code I compiled on our linux cluster. When I run it, I do not get ANY output on the screen and the code crashes. I can see with top that my application starts and allocates memory until it is exhausted (128GB) and killed (by the kernel OOM). I tried using a debugger and I set a breakpoint on main but I still get the same behavior. Therefore I assume that the error happens before getting to main, so I assume that it is related to static/global data initialization or class initialization. I have tried several compiler optimization options and I had some success when using -O0, but with any other optmiazation level they crash. Different behavior with different optimization options suggests to me that there are also problems in the code such as undefined behavior but I also don't know how to approach that.

I know this question is not ideally asked, I do not have a minimal working example. Even though the code is available on public repositories, it is difficult to compile and you need input files to run it that are not publicly available.

This is what I have managed to do so far. I have no idea how to approach this bug, so any ideas or suggestions are more than welcome and I will do my best to answer any questions.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you run it on a single node?

Comment: Sounds like a problem in static initialization.  Set breakpoints in the constructors of global objects.  Maybe use a profiler (if possible) to see what objects are consuming all available memory.

Comment: Have you tried it under Valgrind?

Comment: @AndyG I am running it on a single node with either of one to multiple MPI processes, the behavior is the same.

Comment: @Eljay which profiler are you proposing?

Comment: On Linux, I suppose I'd start with `perf`.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to verify with `strace` that it is not a late `execve` failure. Such failures manifest as an immediate signal after `execve`, without any system calls after the `execve` for the same process.

This happens because `execve` is not atomic: if it has begun replacing the current process image with the new one, but fails afterwards, it will not return with an error (because the original process image it could return to is gone), but instead terminate the process with a signal. The signal varies with kernel versions (either `SIGKILL` or `SIGSEGV`, if I recall correctly). If this happens, it means that your program likely has some very large global variables. They should be visible as large `LOAD` segments with `readelf -lW` and large data sections with `readelf -SW`.

If it is not a late `execve` failure, hopefully the program initialization runs for long enough that you can run it under the debugger and `^C` or send it `SIGINT`, and get a backtrace this way, to see what it is doing. If that does not work, you can set a breakpoint on `__libc_start_main` and step through it until it calls the main program ELF constructors via the `init` function pointer. For ELF constructors in shared objects, you need a breakpoint on `_dl_init` (and also for future glibc versions, probably starting with glibc 2.33 or 2.34; they won't run main program ELF constructors from `__libc_start_main` anymore).